# echo JS functions with PHP variables from SQL query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

I have functions stored in SQL table that I need to use inside JS. The problem is, that I also need to use PHP variables in these functions.

The following:

```
<?php
  $container='11';
  $title='Header';
  $function_text =
  <<<EOT
    $(function() {
      $('#container$container').parent('div').find('h3').html('$title');
    });
  EOT;
  echo $function_text;
?>
```

returns correctly:

```
$(function() {
  $('#container11').parent('div').find('h3').html('Header');
});
```

but this one:

```
<?php
  $ID=1;
  $container='11';
  $title='Header';
  $article = $cls -> Query(sprintf('SELECT * from graphs WHERE ID="%s"', $ID));
  $function_text = $article[0]['function'];
  echo $function_text;
?>
```

prints exactly the contents of SQL field, without recognising variables:

```
$(function() {
  $('#container$container').parent('div').find('h3').html('$title');
});
```

How could I get the variables to be injected to echoed text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change the data that is stored in your database, so that it uses format placeholders instead of references to variables:

   ```
   $(function() {
     $('#container%s').parent('div').find('h3').html('%s');
   });
   ```
2. Use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

   ```php
   $function_text = sprintf($article[0]['function'], $container, $title);
   ```

Comment: thank You, this works, and technically answers my question, but it does not well suit my needs. The code stored in SQL is in fact much longer.  (It's actually used for modifying d3js graphs and uses 20+ variables, so all the %s-s would get very confusing for the editor, and would kill flexibility.) Before accepting Your answer I'd like to know if there's another way, and why isn't simple echoing working.

Comment: @Konservin: The editors can use argument swapping to (numerically) identify exactly to which variable each occurrence refers.  "Simple echoing" isn't working because PHP only parses string literals (and at that, only double-quoted or heredoc ones) for variables; it does not parse strings for variables upon `echo`.  Another option might be to simply search/replace for `$container` etc, perhaps using regular expressions, being careful to handle escaping.  Using `eval()` would more directly do what you ask, but is *far* too dangerous to be tolerated in the real world.